Where can I find an exhaustive list of magic shorthand links?
I would like to find an exhaustive list of shorthand links. A subset of shorthands is listed here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting but the list is not exhaustive.
I'm interested in particular in shorthands for other StackExchange network sites to use in staging ground comments. But a complete reference could be useful in general.
I'm pretty sure that the following list is not complete:

[so], [pt.so], [su], [sf], [metase], [a51], [se] – link to the given site. Link text is the site name.

The shorthand does not seem to follow a simple algorithm, [su] (for superuser) does not appear in the domain name, for example.

That MSE answer is the one I have saved as the comprehensive reference; I'm not sure if another one exists anywhere. Very much agreed that it'd be better in an FAQ/ more authoritative reference though!

All of the ones in the comment thread are in the linked Meta SE answer. balpha and others have done a good job keeping it up to date (far better than any document I've seen in the help list, which requires Moderator or CM privileges to edit).

Magic Links

Characters within the magic links can be any mix of upper and lower case. Some, but not all, of the magic links will respect the case used in the magic link and use the same case for the link text. This is noted in the entry for those which respect case.

On localized sites, the link text for each of the below magic links is localized.


Supported magic links in comments

[meta] – links to the current site's Meta; link text is the site name (e.g. "Meta Super User"). Does nothing if the site doesn't have (or already is) a Meta site.

[main] – like [meta], just the other way around (i.e. it doesn't work on main sites; only works on meta sites which have an associated main site).

[edit] – links to the edit page for the post the comment is on, i.e. /posts/{id}/edit. Link text is "edit" (capitalization is respected).

Help center links.  Link text for all of these is "help center":

[help] – links to the help center (/help).
[meta-help] – links to "What is meta?" (/help/whats-meta)
[help/on-topic] – links to "What topics can I ask about here?" (/help/on-topic).
[help/dont-ask] – links to "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" (/help/dont-ask).
[help/behavior] – links to "What kind of behavior is expected of users?" (/help/behavior).


[tour] or [about] – links to (<main site>/tour). Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link [about] is still supported.

[meta-tour] or [meta-about] – links to (<meta site>/tour). These only work on meta sites. Link text is "tour" (capitalization is respected). Legacy magic link [meta-about] is still supported.

[ask] – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "How to Ask".

[what you are asking] – links to the "How to Ask" page. Link text is "what you are asking".

[answer] – links to the "How to Answer" page. Link text is "How to Answer".

Links to the front page of Stack Exchange sites (link text is the site name):

[so] – links to Stack Overflow
[su] – links to Super User
[sf] – links to Server Fault
[metase]/[meta.se] – links to Meta Stack Exchange
[ubuntu.se] – links to Ask Ubuntu
[mathoverflow.se] – links to MathOverflow
[a51] – links to Area 51
[se] – links to the Stack Exchange
Localized Stack Overflow sites can be linked as

[es.so] – links to Stack Overflow en español
[ja.so] – links to スタック・オーバーフロー
[pt.so] – links to Stack Overflow em Português
[ru.so] – links to Stack Overflow на русском


All other Stack Exchange sites, except Stack Apps:

[something.se] – links to something.stackexchange.com, if that site exists. Link text is the site name.
[sitename.meta.se] or [meta.sitename.se] – links to a site-specific Meta site. Link text is "Meta <sitename>".




[chat] – links to the current site's chat site (https://chat.stackoverflow.com/ for SO, https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/ for Meta SE, https://chat.stackexchange.com/ everywhere else – that last one showing a list of active rooms from the referring site), the link text being "{site name} Chat".

[code block] – links to the "Code and Preformatted Text" section of the Markdown Editing Help page (/editing-help#code). Link text is "code block".

On Stack Overflow only:

[English-only site] – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "Can I ask a question in a language other than English?". Link text is "English-only site".
[help/sg] – links to the (SO-only) Help Center page "What is the Staging Ground?". Link text is "What is the Staging Ground?".


On Stack Overflow and localized Stack Overflow sites (these do not work on the associated meta sites):

[mcve], [reprex], [repro], [mre] and [example] – links to the How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example page for the site. Link text is "minimal reproducible example", or localized text on localized sites. Capitalization doesn't matter and is not respected.


Links to specific tags. These work in questions, answers, comments, and chat – but in comments, they are just formatted like regular links, rather than appearing like tags. Link text is just the name of the tag. These will link to the specified tag, regardless of whether the tag actually exists:

[tag:tag-name] creates a link to the named tag on the main site, e.g tag-name. (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the main site.)
[meta-tag:meta-tag-name] creates a link to a tag on meta, e.g meta-tag-name. (Whether it's used on the main site or the meta site, the link will point to a tag on the meta site.)
(On Meta Stack Exchange, which doesn't have a main site, [tag:tag-name] and [meta-tag:tag-name] work exactly the same way.)



This answer was copied on 2024-10-17 from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/613724 and is now maintained separately to include StackOverflow-specific magic links and remove parts that are not applicable

Hum, your Answer is mostly "Link-only" actually, not best, I would think... => Copy here the 'Comment formatting' section from the 'Markdown help' Page you've linked to... Then make your Answer a 'Community Wiki Answer', ... and we can start updating/keeping it up to date,  ... like adding [mre] for example, and a few others...

@chivracq happy to do this if that's what people agree would be the best solution - my links were first an update to the question, then turned into self-answer upon request in comments

I've copied over and left a note in italics at the bottom showing the origin and linking back to it. - It's also a community wiki now.

is that useful? "please read [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]". i expected the title of the help page to appear instead of "help center" (probably not the right place to say that but i don't know where to)
